# Algorithms/methods to create more features of a limited amount of features?

Tags: svm, feature-selection, feature-engineering

So, let's suppose that I have a set of 20 features - some of them are continous and some of them are binary.

Is there an algorithm/method/solution to create more features ( combine/transform ) those features ( for example by using 2 of them to create another feature )?

I want to do this to give a linear SVM more features to look at - is this a good thing to do or a big no-no?

Would this be called increasing the dimensionality of the dataset?

Can I extract more data out of those 20 numbers by creating new variables of their combinations?

If this matters at all, I use a linear kernel.

Comment: it's an idea that's been used frequently since 25 years at least. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to expand a bit the comment of user603.

You can do what you propose and usually it helps if you have a large enough sample. Indeed, this process will lead to increasing the dimensionality of the space. The increased dimensionality is the reason you need more samples.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use a non-linear kernel (aka deploy a kernel trick). For example, using a polynomial kernel of degree 2 will "create" features by doing pairwise combination of your features. Similarly, for a polynomial kernel of degree 3 you will end up with combinations of triplets of features.

The trade-off of using a non-linear kernel is that solutions are in the dual, i.e. you end up with combinations of features that you can not interpret directly, e.g., you can't make directly statements like "features A,B,C and/or their combinations are the most important".